# Why Xcode says that my team has no device to use for development when clearly an iPhone device is connected

Tags: xcode4.5, publishing

Your team has no devices for which to generate a provisioning profile. Please connect a device to use for development, or manually add a Device ID using the Provisioning Portal.
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/iOS

Okay. So it says that I don't have a device. Please connect a device. Connect a device to what? I already have my iPhone connected to iMac

Going to
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/iOS

end up with me seeing:

We are unable to process your request.

Please go back to the previous page, or quit your browser and try your request again.

Comment: well, did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the device, then go to the organizer tab in xcode, select the connected device, and on the left side pane, click on "Use this device for development"

Comment: Where is the button that says Use this device for development?

Comment: Organizer->Devices, on the left pane will be a list of device, choose your device, then on the right pane the button will be present

Comment: I select the device. There is no button saying use this device for development. Right clicking the device has something along add this to provisioning profile though.